# Hibernate Criteria Query ...Adding a new condition

Tags: java, hibernate, jakarta-ee, criteria

I have a criteria query that works just fine.

```
Criteria criteria = getSession().createCriteria(getPersistentClass());
criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("employerId",employerId))
        .setFetchMode("card", FetchMode.JOIN)
        .createCriteria("card")
        .addOrder(Order.desc("cardId"))
        .createCriteria("salary")
        .add(Restrictions.eq("salaryType",SalaryIdentifierType.CONTRACTOR))
        .add(Restrictions.eq("active","YES"));
```

Now, i need to add another filter(condition) to this criteria. The new filter is `joinDate`. If the `joinDate` value has been passed from the Frontend, i will have to add it to this query or else, the filter `joinDate` should not be added.

I have managed to do this using a disjunction(I know, its weird...but AFAIK, only disjunction gives the the facility to add the filter at the runtime, only it if is present). I did it like this, but i do not want to use a disjunction here and I am looking for other options.

```
Criteria criteria = getSession().createCriteria(getPersistentClass());
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
Disjunction disjunctionDate = Restrictions.disjunction(); 
  if(utilDate!=null){
    disjunctionDate = (Disjunction) disjunctionDate.add(Restrictions.ge("startDate",  utilDate));
    } 
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
    criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("employerId",employerId))
            .setFetchMode("card", FetchMode.JOIN)
            .createCriteria("card")
            .addOrder(Order.desc("cardId"))
            .createCriteria("salary")
            .add(Restrictions.eq("salaryType",SalaryIdentifierType.CONTRACTOR))
            .add(Restrictions.eq("active","YES"))
                .add(disjunctionDate);
```

I have tried just using if condition, like this but does not work(To even make this compile, i had to modify the query format from above to having criteria in every line and semicolon in every line).

```
Criteria criteria = getSession().createCriteria(getPersistentClass());
    criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("employerId",employerId));
    criteria.setFetchMode("card", FetchMode.JOIN);
    criteria.createCriteria("card");
    criteria.addOrder(Order.desc("cardId"));
    criteria.createCriteria("salary");
    criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("salaryType",SalaryIdentifierType.CONTRACTOR));
    criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("active","YES"));
    if(startDate!=null){
       criteria.add(Restrictions.ge("startDate",startDate));
     }
```

Any ideas on how to make this work with better options than using disjunction?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So you are saying this is not working for you?

```
Criteria criteria = getSession().createCriteria(getPersistentClass())
  .add(Restrictions.eq("employerId",employerId))
  .setFetchMode("card", FetchMode.JOIN)
  .createCriteria("card")
  .addOrder(Order.desc("cardId"))
  .createCriteria("salary", "sl")  // <- alias for salary
  .add(Restrictions.eq("sl.salaryType",SalaryIdentifierType.CONTRACTOR))
  .add(Restrictions.eq("sl.active","YES"));

if(startDate!=null) {
  criteria.add(Restrictions.ge("sl.startDate",startDate));
}
```

See http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.1/manual/en-US/html_single/#querycriteria-associations

Comment: yes..it is not working...basically "statrtDate" is in salary table but not on the "getPersistentClass()" table. In the code shown in your post, hibernate will try to find startDate column in "getPersistentClass()" table. Hence it wont work

Comment: In your question you did not mentioned that startDate is in the other table. Anyway I edited my answer. You need to specify alias for salary.